# How to validate if the input matches a specific timestamp format?

Tags: java, regex, validation, formatting, timestamp

I need to check if the input matches to the timestamp format **`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`**.

> Eg. 2012-08-16T11:07:10.793

How can I do it?

Comment: Can't you just convert the input to a date object and then perform comparison?

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Or Googled for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    date = (Date) formatter.parse("2012-08-16T11:07:10.793");
} catch(ParseException e) {
    // It does not match your input
}
```

Or, as always use a regular expresion...

EDIT:
Taken maba's typo spotting into account.

Comment: Your current format string will not work. Try it out and you will get this date if you print the `date` variable : *Thu Aug 16 13:19:13 CEST 2012*. You will have to change format string to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`, upercase `S` for the milliseconds. And also change the `7933` to `793` as in his example. Right now this answer is wrong so why the upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
^(\d{4})\D?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\D?([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01])(\D?([01]\d|2[0-3])\D?([0-5]\d)\D?([0-5]\d)?\D?(\d{3})?)?$
```

Sorry for the late edit. 
If you only want to check if the pattern of the date matches you can use the regex like this:

```
    String date = "2012-08-16T11:07:10.793";
    String regex = "^(\\d{4})\\D?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\D?([12]\\d|0[1-9]|3[01])(\\D?([01]\\d|2[0-3])\\D?([0-5]\\d)\\D?([0-5]\\d)?\\D?(\\d{3})?)?$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(date);

    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Yes it matches");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
```

Comment: The regex is correct but you should elaborate on how the OP should use it. Maybe an example with `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

Comment: Can you please update the above to include a regex for the following format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.hhhZ` ... come to think of it, it should be with a Z at the end?